# maven plugin dependency scope in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, war, maven-plugin

I use maven to package my web application, but I found that a lot of maven jars are in my war's lib directory. I do not  think they are useful for my web application under tomcat, so how can I exclude them?

[image: some jars]

```
      <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.13</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.13</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.13</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.13</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.whalin</groupId>
      <artifactId>Memcached-Java-Client</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.imgscalr</groupId>
      <artifactId>imgscalr-lib</artifactId>
      <version>4.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.4</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.4</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.14</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.13</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.13</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.5</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.logback-extensions</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-ext-spring</artifactId>
      <version>0.1.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
      <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.1.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
      <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
      <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
      <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mybatis.generator</groupId>
      <artifactId>mybatis-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>google-collect</artifactId>
          <groupId>com.google.code.google-collections</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.shardbatis</groupId>
      <artifactId>shardbatis</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0B</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.jsqlparser</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsqlparser</artifactId>
      <version>0.7.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.yolu.wrm</groupId>
      <artifactId>trendrr-beanstalk</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <version>1.8</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sourceforge.cardme</groupId>
      <artifactId>cardme</artifactId>
      <version>0.4.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>3.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.yolu.wrm</groupId>
      <artifactId>weibo4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>


  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>/Users/mbao/workspace/wrm-server/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>/Users/mbao/workspace/wrm-server/src/main/scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>/Users/mbao/workspace/wrm-server/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>/Users/mbao/workspace/wrm-server/target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>/Users/mbao/workspace/wrm-server/target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>/Users/mbao/workspace/wrm-server/src/main/java</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.xml</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>/Users/mbao/workspace/wrm-server/src/main/resources/dev</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>/Users/mbao/workspace/wrm-server/src/test/resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <directory>/Users/mbao/workspace/wrm-server/target</directory>
    <finalName>wrm-server###1.0</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.mybatis.generator</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.14</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <configuration>
          <verbose>true</verbose>
          <overwrite>true</overwrite>
          <configurationFile>/Users/mbao/workspace/wrm-server/src/main/resources/dev/generatorConfig.xml</configurationFile>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.6</source>
              <target>1.6</target>
              <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
              <compilerArguments>
                <extdirs>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib</extdirs>
              </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.6</source>
              <target>1.6</target>
              <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
              <compilerArguments>
                <extdirs>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib</extdirs>
              </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
          <compilerArguments>
            <extdirs>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib</extdirs>
          </compilerArguments>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-war</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>war</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <webResources>
                <resource>
                  <directory>src/main/resources/dev</directory>
                  <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                  <directory>web/WEB-INF/</directory>
                  <targetPath>WEB-INF/</targetPath>
                </resource>
              </webResources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <webResources>
            <resource>
              <directory>src/main/resources/dev</directory>
              <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
            </resource>
            <resource>
              <directory>web/WEB-INF/</directory>
              <targetPath>WEB-INF/</targetPath>
            </resource>
          </webResources>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testResources</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testResources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-site</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>/Users/mbao/workspace/wrm-server/target/site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>site-deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>/Users/mbao/workspace/wrm-server/target/site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>/Users/mbao/workspace/wrm-server/target/site</outputDirectory>
          <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </reportPlugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

[image]

Comment: those are maven jars, how did they get in ? can you post your `mvn help:effective-pom` ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi  updated.  Yes, they are maven jars, but I do not think they effect in war file. Right?

Comment: Can you attach the result of `mvn dependency:tree` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try change

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mybatis.generator</groupId>
  <artifactId>mybatis-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.2</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>google-collect</artifactId>
      <groupId>com.google.code.google-collections</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mybatis.generator</groupId>
  <artifactId>mybatis-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.2</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>google-collect</artifactId>
      <groupId>com.google.code.google-collections</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

EDIT: above is only quick fix, generally you should get rid of this type of dependencies, plugin usage should be defined in pluginManagement.

Comment: A plugin should never be used as a dependency this is simply wrong.

Comment: @khmarbaise you are perfectly right. i just gave simpliest should which should be used as quick fix. Will edit my post.

Answer (score 8):

Simply answer. Never use maven plugins as dependencies cause they do not belong to dependencies. That's the reason why got those strange artifacts in your build.

Answer (score 2):

You should update the scope section for the dependencies ,which you want to exclude in the war file.

```
<scope>provided</scope>
```

provided scope indicates the dependency will be present during compilation,but will not be included in war file.

For more information you can refer :-

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

And for the maven related jar you can exclude them using below.

```
<configuration>
      <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</packagingExcludes>
</configuration>
```